# Mutual information conditioned on Z = z

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I understand that the Mutual information I(X : Y ) can be calculated as follows:
 [mutual information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v6SC.png)
While the Conditional Mutual information I(X; Y |Z) can be calculated as follows: 
[conditional mutual information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HWF3.png)

If I want to calculate the mutual information between X and Y conditioned on Z = z which can be denoted as 
I(X : Y |Z=z) how can I do that ?
and how this can be derived from the equations before ? is there any reference for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the mutual information (or joint entropy... or whatever) conditioned on a particular value of $Z$, you simply replace all the probabilities functions by the corresponding conditional probabilities.

Say, you know (among other equivalent formulas) that

$$I(X;Y)=H(X) - H(X\mid Y)=\\
E_{X,Y}[\log(\frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X)P(Y)})]$$

Then

$$I(X;Y\mid Z=z)=H(X\mid Z=z) - H(X\mid Y, Z=z)=\\
E_{X,Y\mid Z=z}[\log(\frac{p(X,Y \mid Z=z)}{p(X\mid Z=z)P(Y\mid Z=z)})]$$

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your reply ... however, I couldn't find any source which I can refer to when using this formula ? can you please refer me to any ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the second formula, and look at the summation on $Z$ (the outermost): that sum has a single element, obtained assigning the single value you want to $Z$.

Let me add that the notation you are using, is very confusing combined with that of the formulas you include (is Z a variable? A set? etc.)

Comment: I thought like that but I have found some replaced the  p(x, y, z) before the log with p(x, y|z) only .. and of course this will lead to different answer .. which one of them is correct ? Z is a random variable